# jquery var for firebase database path

Tags: jquery, firebase-realtime-database, assembly-reference-path

```
//this is short hand not actual code please

var =  trainNum = 0;

// on button click

trainNum++;

// I can't figure out the format to put in so that firebase treats trainNum as the variable and not a string.
 database.ref(Trains/**I WANT THIS TO EQUAL THE trainNum as it increments **).push({
});

//Train number is being stored in database I don't know if this will effect outcome.
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the trainNum from database, and not set it to 0.

Im not sure if that was your question?

Comment: Sorry not quite don't the format so that firebase will treat trainNum as the variable and not treat it as a string.

Comment: It shouldn't treat it as string. You cant increment string.

Comment: If its a string, you should convert it into an int with: 
var trainInt = parseInt(trainNum); 
trainInt++;

Comment: Ahh yea, thats right. But you still have to convert it to int, so you can increment the value.

Comment: When you type it into the ref() function for firebase, firebase treats it as a string when saving assigning it as the path.                                                                      example of firebase database
 
Trian                                                                                                                                    ----TrainNum
------data
----TrainNum                                                                                                             

What I want to be               

Train
----1
------data
----2
------data

Comment: Could u try `database.ref(Trains/${trainNum}).push({})` ?

Comment: it would be database.ref("train/" + trainNumber)